# Django - How to access the first featured post of my blog?

Tags: django

In my blog's model, I have a boolean flag to determine if a post is "featured" or not. Featured posts will be displayed in a different way.

To retrieve the posts I have defined two model managers as below:

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class FeaturedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(FeaturedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(feature=True).order_by('-publish')[:3]
```

and in the **views.py** this is how I pass them to the template:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['featured'] = Post.featured.all()
        return context
```

Now in my template I have a section for featured posts and another section for normal posts. Normal posts are easy, but I want to display the **first featured post** — which is going to be the most recent one — in a separate container, and the last two in another one. There always will be the last 3 featured posts displayed.

Here's the code for template to display the first featured post:

```
                    <div class="jumbotron p-4 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
                        <div class="col-md-10 px-0">
                            <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">The Title of Newest Featured Post</h1>
                            <p class="lead my-3">The Body of the Newest Featured Post</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My question is, how to access the first, second and third posts in `featured` object?

Comment: Hi, why not using the same way that you used in the `FeaturedManager` and do something like `context['featured'] = Post.featured.all()[:3]`

Comment: I know how to retrieve the last 3 and pass it to the template. I need to access the first one in my template and that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, you can simple use Jinja `templatetags` and especially something like `{{ featured[0] }} or {{  featured | first }}`

Comment: ```featured[0]``` returns ```Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'featured[0]'``` and ```featured | first``` does not allow me to access model fields like ```title``` and ```body```. Remember they are blog posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is to use `queryset.index` in the template:

`featured.0` for the first, `featured.1` for second and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic

```
  <p class="lead my-3">{{ featured | first }}</p>
  OR
  <p class="lead my-3">{{ featured[0] }}</p>

...

  <p class="lead my-3">{{ featured[1] }}</p>
etc.
```

Of course you can create your own `templatetags` and use them whenever you need them.

- Create a new folder under your project root folder with the name `templatetags`
- Add an empty `__init__.py` file
- Create a new file with the name `second.py`
- Add the following code

```
import os

from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def second(list):
  return list[1]
```

- On the top of your template html file where you want to use it add the following line `{% load second %}`
- Use the following code `{{ featured | second:ADD_THE_LIST }}`

In case that you want to read more about the `templatetags` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Each post has a ```title```, a ```lead``` and a ```body```. Please tell me how to access those in my template.

Comment: Pretty easy `{{ featured.title | second:ADD_THE_LIST }}`, `{{ featured.lead | second:ADD_THE_LIST }}` etc.

Comment: Would you please provide the solution without custom templatetags?

Comment: You can convert your queryset into a list and use the `{{ featured[0].title }}` solution.

Comment: I changed it to ```context['featured'] = list(Post.featured.all())``` but ```{{ featured[0].title }}``` still gives me ```Could not parse the remainder: '[0].title' from 'featured[0].title'```

Comment: Even creating a separate list by ```featured_list = list(Post.featured.all())``` and adding it to context with ```context['featured']=featured_list``` gives me exact same error :(

Comment: @OmidShojaee thanks for your comment, I replied with the correct approach you should follow (template tags). Did you try it out?

Comment: No because I'm not sure what ```ADD_THE_LIST``` is referring to.

Comment: Apparently the answer was simple.